# Getting house neighbors using GeoDjango?

Tags: python, geodjango

i have a house model with these properties

```
centerpoint = PointField(srid=0, null=True, blank=True)
front_left = PointField(srid=0, null=True, blank=True)
front_right = PointField(srid=0, null=True, blank=True)
rear_left = PointField(srid=0, null=True, blank=True)
rear_right = PointField(srid=0, null=True, blank=True)
polygon = PolygonField(srid=0, null=True, blank=True)
direction = FloatField(null=True, blank=True)  # the direction this house faces, in degrees
```

and i want to get the houses in front of a specific house... im having a hard time trying to use Distance and polygon__dwithin

i need to get the ones that are touching and the ones that have relative direction of less than 160 degrees:

for that i do:

```
House.objects.filter(polygon__touches=house_instance.polygon, direction__lt=160)
```

how can i modify this query to get the houses that are in front maximum one block and the ones that are one house away from my reference house?

also is it possible to get the neighbors by using my polygon field to get the closest polygon fields from it?